# Is it possible to apply a CSS style to the container element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am looking for a selector which applies to any div element that contains an element identified by the p.my selector

```
<div>
 <p class="my">
  prova
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no specific parent selector in CSS, but I know two other ways:

1. You just give the `<div>` a class or id.
2. You could install jquery and use:
   `$('p.my').parent().css({/*some css*/});`